# Can custom content be imported into LEGO Creator?

Tags: video-games

I was reading [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Creator_%28video_game%29#Custom_models) Wikipedia article that states:

> Some people have uploaded custom (Lego) model creations for others to
>   download into their version of Lego Creator. Tools used include LDraw,
>   LegoDigitalDesigner and other LCA model format model software.

Is this possible, and can custom shaped or coloured bricks be imported?

Comment: Purely out of curiosity, is there a reason you want to use Creator rather then LDD or something else a bit more modern?

Comment: Probably because Creator allows you to interact with models instead of simply view them. Do you know someone that shares lca models?

Comment: Normally a statement like that on Wikipedia would require a citation - odd that it's missing... Anyway, digging around elsewhere, the Brick model files had more than just the model data - they had actions, etc. associated with them, so aren't the same format as the LDD elements. http://www.rockraidersunited.org/topic/2944-lego-creator/

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, that's not a factual statement.  [I contacted the Wikipedia user who added that content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_talk%3aGaming4JC#LEGO_Creator), and he informed me that that statement was in error.  You can add custom models, but not directly from LDraw, LDD, or similar tools.